Error when Deploying SPFx Package to SP2019 On-Premises Production Site
We're utilizing SPFx version 1.4.1 for SharePoint 2019 On-Premises. In our dedicated virtual machine (VM), development is carried out on our internal domain. Deploying to /sites/AppCatalog presents no issues.
However, when attempting to upload the package to the production site with a different web application name, we encounter an error. It indicates that the solution will retrieve content from:

This client side solution will get content from the following domains:
HTTPS://SPCLIENTSIDEASSETLIBRARY/; https://{vmlocaldomain}

This points to our VM's domain. How should we configure our SPFx solution to address this?
